# Display data from 2 tables with SUM and COUNT

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display results from 2 different tables using Inner Join, sum and count. I am having alot of difficulty making it work.

```
Table properties
+----+--------+---------+-------+-------+
| id | idname | address | pic1  | ll_id |
+----+--------+---------+-------+-------+
|  1 | apt1   |    1344 | 1.jpg |     1 |
|  2 | apt2   |    1345 | 2.jpg |     1 |
+----+--------+---------+-------+-------+

Table transactions
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | property_id | revenue |
+----+-------------+---------+
|  1 |           1 |    1000 |
|  2 |           1 |     500 |
|  3 |           2 |     300 |
|  4 |           2 |     100 |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

I need to display it in the following way

```
+------+---------+-------+--------------+-------------+
| name | address |  pic  | total(count) | total (sum) |
+------+---------+-------+--------------+-------------+
| apt1 |    1344 | 1.jpg |            2 |        1500 |
| apt2 |    1345 | 2.jpg |            2 |         400 |
+------+---------+-------+--------------+-------------+
```

here is the code i am using

```php
$llid = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]);
$sql = "SELECT name, address, pic1 from properties 
INNER JOIN
(select SUM(revenue) as revenue, count(id) from transactions)
where properties.ll_id = " .$llid. "";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["address"];?></td>
         <td> <img src="p3/img/<?php echo $row["pic1"];?>" width="80"> </td>
         <td><?php echo $row["id"];?></td>
         <td>$<?php echo $row["revenue"];?></td>
         <td> <span>VIEW</span> </td>
        </tr>
<?php

    }

} else {
    echo "No Updates";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the aggregation inside your `JOIN` query without using a subquery. Note that you probably want to use a `LEFT JOIN` in case a property has no transactions

```
SELECT p.name, p.address, p.pic1 AS pic,
       COALESCE(COUNT(t.property_id), 0) AS `total (count)`,
       COALESCE(SUM(t.revenue), 0) AS `total (sum)`
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.property_id = p.id
WHERE p.ll_id = 1
GROUP BY p.name, p.address, p.pic1
```

Output:

```
name    address pic     total (count)   total (sum)
apt1    1344    1.jpg   2               1500
apt2    1345    2.jpg   2               400
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGA4sxhcyRMwfNRvQ63z5z/2)

In PHP you could write:

```
$llid = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION["id"]);
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.name, p.address, p.pic1 AS pic,
       COALESCE(COUNT(t.property_id), 0) AS `transactions`,
       COALESCE(SUM(t.revenue), 0) AS `revenue`
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.property_id = p.id
WHERE p.ll_id = $llid
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.address, p.pic1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row["name"];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row["address"];?></td>
         <td> <img src="p3/img/<?php echo $row["pic"];?>" width="80"> </td>
         <td><?php echo $row["transactions"];?></td>
         <td>$<?php echo $row["revenue"];?></td>
         <td> <span>VIEW</span> </td>
        </tr>
<?php

    }

} else {
    echo "No Updates";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: can you please show me how to display it in PHP. How would i display the results of the sum and count?

Comment: I tried that, the first 3 work (name, address, pic) but revenue and id dont show. it shows blank.

Comment: @user3427496 did you copy my code exactly? It shouldn't be possible to get blank values if you did.

Comment: i replaced $row["id"] with $row["transactions"] and it worked. thanks for the help.